# How can I remove the "More Views" in my product pages?

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I tried to find "More Views" in my view.phtml file but I found nothing. I'm using the RWD theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find **More Views** block in media.phtml under `theme_directory/template/catalog/product/` directory.